# Can I use the BaseColor class in old iText versions?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, acrofields

I am trying to set BorderColor to an AcroField of my PDF.
We are using an iText version that is at least 5 years old. I dont see any class named `BaseColor` in that version, whereas I've seen the following code being used in more recent versions of the iText library:

`AcroFields form  = New AcroFields ();
form.setFieldProperty("text_2", "bordercolor", BaseColor.RED, null);`

Is there are anyway I can successfully use `BaseColor` in the obsolete versions of iText?

I also have a follow-up question: [Can I find bordercolor of a field in PDF using iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312620/can-i-find-bordercolor-of-a-field-in-pdf-using-itext)

Comment: `BaseColor` does not exist in obsolete versions of iText. Please don't call those versions Lowagie. Lowagie is how people call *me* (it's my *name*!), not the software I wrote. The software has always been named iText!

Comment: *The software has always been named iText!* ... And the best way to indicate its development state is by giving its version number.

Comment: I am sorry @Bruno Lowagie. The import appeared on that name(lowagie) instead of iText, so I used that way.  `import com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields;` I realize its an older version and needs to be upgraded. Thanks.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie  Could you please let me know if there is a way of finding bordercolor using iText latest version? I updated my question as well. Thanks.

Comment: You'll find my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312620/can-i-find-bordercolor-of-a-field-in-pdf-using-itext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
//import java.awt.Color;
fields.setFieldProperty("text_2", "bordercolor", Color.BLUE, null);
fields.setFieldProperty("text_2", "bordercolor", Color.RED, null);
fields.setFieldProperty("text_2", "bordercolor", Color.GREEN, null);
```

If you need a custom color, define it like this:

```
Color custom = new Color(228,102,0);
fields.setFieldProperty("text_2", "bordercolor", custom, null);
```